# Why do I get a syntax error "Unexpected Identifier" when trying to decrease i in my for loop?

Tags: google-apps-script, syntax-error

In the following code, I get an "Unexpected Identifier" syntax error at the line with "i--;". This is for moving data (copying to another sheet and deleting the row in the original sheet) in a Google sheets file (using Google Apps Script). The function I'm passing i to deletes a row in the original sheet, so the for loop effectively skips a row in its checking. To fix this I wanted to decrease i by 1 when the if statement condition is satisfied. I tried "i--;", "i=i-1;", and more, but none of them work!

```
    for(var i=2; i<=lastRow; i++)
     { 
       Logger.log(i);
       if(rasPI.getRange(i,14).getValue() <= -1)
        (
          copyDelete(i)
          i--;
        )
     }'
```

Comment: It should be written like this `for (var i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++) {
  Logger.log(i);
  if (rasPI.getRange(i, 14).getValue() <= -1) {copyDelete(i);i--;}}` You have parenthesis where there should be brackets.  And copyDelete(i) is undefined.  Please provide [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You need curly brackets `{}` not normal ones `()` after the if statement.

```js
for (var i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++){
    Logger.log(i);
    if (rasPI.getRange(i, 14).getValue() <= -1)
    {
        copyDelete(i);
        i--;
    }
}
```

If that is still not working then provide the code for `copyDelete`